# Varying vibration intensity: how does the VIBE app do it?

Tags: android, vibration, android-vibration

I understand that, given how vibration is achieved, the only way to vary the intensity would be a way to control the RPM of the motor. I can see the [Vibrator Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html) does not allow for this, and yet, the VIBE app [(see this video)](http://youtu.be/TNGE0PEDcA4) appears to be achieving just that. On the video, at about 0:35, the "create your own vibe" is briefly shown. I tested it and, by god, it appears to be varying the intensity. Could it be that they are using the NDK for direct motor control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ViBe uses the [Immersion Haptic SDK](http://www.immersion.com/products/haptic-sdk/) to control the device vibrations. Immersion themselves 
are using the Android NDK internally.