# Android. How to make vibration when device vibration level setted to 0?

Tags: android, android-vibration

I've got a problem. I need to make a vibration after some user's action, so I've used the code:

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
v.vibrate(300);
```

But I've got a problem.
When I test the app on the device, where vibration level setted to 0, there is no vibration from my app.

How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In case user turns down the volume to Silent not vibrate(it also works if the user sets vibration to disabled) you can use this:

```
    ...

    AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);



            Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

            if (am.getRingerMode() ==  AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT)
            {
                v.vibrate(300);
            }
            else
            {
                v.vibrate(500);
            }
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn down the volume to Silent does not cause this problem. Instead, 
I noticed that it is the `Notifications` field in `Setting> Sound> Vibration intensity` that control the vibration level.
That's why even AudioManager would not work:

```
private AudioManager myAudioManager;
myAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); 
myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
```

However, there was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884286/varying-vibration-intensity-how-does-the-vibe-app-do-it?rq=1) and the answer to that was to use [Immersion Haptic SDK](http://www.immersion.com/products/haptic-sdk/).

Hope this help.